# C# HttpClient - PostAsync doesn't return (even with ConfigureAwait)

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, httpclient, blocking

I am running crazy with using the HttpClient in C#...

I simplified my project so my problem can be replicated easier. All i want to do is calling HttpClient.PostAsync in the Background without blocking my UI Window (I am using WPF btw).

Here is my code (slimed the code to the min.):
Bing is only used here to not show my private webservice it can be replaced with every other website of course.

```
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Waiting...";

            Uri webUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com/");
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(webUri, new MultipartFormDataContent())) {
                    MyTextBlock.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                       
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString(), "Unhandled Exception");
        }
    }
```

While my UI is waiting for the async post request it shows "Waiting" in a TextBox. And when the Async Request returns it shows the result. Nothing more should happen.

So here the Problem occurs, sometimes the PostAsync Method simply doesn't return... Even the Timeout is ignored. When I am debugging it always works but when I try the start the application it somettimes hangs. Not always which is not making find the error easier. I tried many ways with calling the request async but every time the same issue.

I also read following blog with the blocking issue in async methods but even with ConfigureAwait no differnce. 
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

I just can imagine that there is a problem within the HttpClient async method locking the main thread, so it cause this problem. Wenn i use the same code in a ConsoleApplication everything is fine. There is a proxy between my client and the destination but that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Can someone replicate this problem? I am using C#/WPF with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Why are you wrapping an async call in a call to `Task.Run` (which you don't even await)?

Comment: Can you remove `Task.Run` and just make `Window_Loaded` an async method? It doesn't need to return Task as it is an event handler. Then you also would not need `Dispatcher`.

Comment: @PeterBons: Because i don't want to await the request in my UI Thread. The UI should always go on. Or what is you solution for this??

Comment: @Momo using `async/await` allows you to make `UI` responsive without the need of creating new thread, so if you just await it without `Task.Run` it will not block your `UI`.

Comment: @FCin Of course I can call and await the Methods directly but i still have to use the Dispatcher (otherwise InvalidOperationException => The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it). And it doesn't solve the problem, even without Task.Run the same issue appears... Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Using `ConfigureAwait()` determines if the Task should return to the original thread. In the majority of cases it will be false, however on UI and web contexts it should be true

Comment: @JLevett okay i read differnt oppinions on ConfigureAwait with true/false or using Result etc. It seems everybody says something different^^ But i tried it and it seems to work for the moment :) but let my give it a long time check if it really works, because the issue appeared very unevenly... I will post it as answer if it really works. But can you explaine why true is the right solution??

Comment: The official documentation states that the bool `continueOnCapturedContext` is to `attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured` - So in this instance we want to return to the UI thread and update our variable, rather than getting any thread available from the pool. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @JLevett ahhh come on... it happend again. problem still there :(

Comment: But with ConfigureAwait(true) i don't need the Dispatcher so @FCin was right when it is set to false. because the instance will return to the UI thread.

Comment: Just a note that [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). `HttpClient` is fully thread-safe and reentrant, even though it is `IDisposable` you shouldn't actually use it that way. It was designed to be used as a single, shared instance within your application. Most likely not related to your current problem, but I thought it would be helpful for you to know about.

Comment: @BradleyUffner so best practice is creating it at application start up and dispose is it on application closing?

Comment: @Momo Yes, that's the pattern that really seems to be recommended by Microsoft people in various blogs posts I've seen. If you are not making a lot of HTTP requests in a short amount of time, or are just banging out a quick program, it probably won't hurt to keep doing what you are doing, but keep it in mind if you ever write anything that makes a lot of requests, or is performance sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all thanks for your help, the problem seems to be solved now.

I had to do 3 things to get this work:

1. Get a instance of HttpClient of use it the whole application life time, so no using anymore for HttpClient.
2. Don't call PostAsync in the Window_Loaded Event, it seems to be to early sometimes. (I still don't get why...)
3. Don't use ConfigureAwait(false)

The code now looks something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        MyTextBlock.Text = "Waiting...";
        Uri webUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com/");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(webUri, new ipartFormDataContent())) {
            MyTextBlock.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString(), "Unhandled Exception");
    }
}
```

And to get this at start up done i had to make a really bad piece of good. But it works finally:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer startupTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    startupTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((o, a) => {
        MyFunction();
        startupTimer.Stop();
    });
    startupTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    startupTimer.Start();
}
```

When someone can replicate these behavior or can explain why these was happening, please comment it here :)

---

**Update**

Issue still occurs but it seems to be only there when the client is using some kind of proxy!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to `await` `client.PostAsync(webUri, i_formData)` because you don't do anything with the result after the call returns, you can just return the `Task`. Change to this;

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> BasicRequest(MultipartFormDataContent i_formData)
{
    Uri webUri = new Uri("https://www.bing.com");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    };
    return client.PostAsync(webUri, i_formData);
}
```

Your `Window_Load` is an event handler. You can make it `async void`, which is the only time you don't have to return `Task`. By making it `async`, you can remove all the over complicated code:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBlock.Text = "Waiting";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await BasicRequest(new 
    MultipartFormDataContent());
    string test = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats a good hint. It slimes the good down. But unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: Silly question but are you posting to bing.com?

Comment: :D just replaced my private WebServer with something not so privat :D don't want everybody sitting on my webserver. But the logic stays the same so i took bing :D

Comment: Ah ok, yes, that makes sense. Thought you were trying to hit up bing.com and they might have some throttling or whatever. Have you tried wrapping your `Window_Load` code in a `try catch`? You might be getting some `AggregateException`

Comment: Yes of course, i tried that, even with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. But the only exception that appears here is after a few minutes i get a Thread was canceled exception. But i didn't get the real problem here. i was already thinging about a network problem.. but shouldn't the timeout be raised then?

Comment: You're never disposing your `HttpClient`, so it might be tying up some unmanaged resources. Have a look at [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) article about `HttpClient`

Comment: Ohh sorry i have a using block around it just lost will i was simplifyng my code i will fix this.